# HTTPPost is not allowed by production WebServer for WebAPI (aspnetcore 2.2)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, http-post, http-status-code-404

I have the following code in the StartUp.ConfigureServices

```
  services.AddCors(c=>c.AddPolicy(Konstants.CORS, d=>
                    d.AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowCredentials()
                    )
                );
```

and in the Configure method I use the following as the first line:

```
app.UseCors(Konstants.CORS);
```

On every controller for web api I use the following

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [EnableCors(Konstants.CORS)]
    [ApiController, Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [Consumes("application/json"), Produces("application/json")]
    public class EmployeesController : ApiBaseController
    {
```

On local machines everything runs fine. But on remote machine i.e. the production one, HTTPGet works fine but for all HTTPPOST it returns 404.

here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\myapp.Web.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

What could be the issue? I have access to webserver through plesk.
A few details I missed. This website has regular controllers as well as API controllers hosted in the same app. for api controller we use JWTToken for other controllers we use cookies. Website works just fine. Api controllers have all Get Requests work fine and they even fetch the data from database correctly (so at least its not a DB issue) but all api POST return 404. URL not found.

As @Anton asked, here is one of the post request

```
[HttpPost("Start")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> StartJob([FromBody] JobActivityModel model)
        {
            var ret = Empty;

            try
            {

                await Execute(new StartJob
                {
                    JobId = model.JobId,
                    PersonId = UserId,
                    At = model.CreatedAt
                });

                Log.Info($"{SoligoUser} has started the job");

                ret = Ok(new TimeClue
                {
                    Message = "job has been started",
                    IsSuccess = true,
                    Time = model.CreatedAt
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex);
                ret = Error(ex);
            }

            return ret;
        }
```

Comment: You are most likely hitting a 500, and then if you don't have an Error handling page it gives you a 404. Because it's happening on `POST` I am assuming you are trying to write something to the database. Check that the database is working. Above all enable developers exception page.

Comment: Database should be working fine because all get requests that also hit the database return data correctly. So I assume it's not really related to database. I have added extensive logging but the API controller is not even reached.

Comment: It might be worth showing an example of actions that you area trying to hit.

Comment: Yep, added a post request in my question so you can see the code. It's not even hitting that.

Answer (score 0):

You may try below things.

1. Install [swagger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle/) and try
2. [RDP](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000471413-How-to-connect-to-a-Plesk-server-via-RDP-with-available-credentials) in to server and try to run on server. This will give exact error.
3. Check headers of post request you tried with server.
4. Double check paths and payloads are correct
5. Follow this to [host .net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) in iis.
6. Check you are sending correct tokens to server

Comment: My provider has RDP access disallowed and he mentioned it is not possible for security reasons.

Comment: Try swagger then.

Answer (score 0):

After much time wasted on web searches this turned out to be the solution:

[image]

Adding this line solved all the issues. Post is now working correctly and sometimes the Media Not Supported Error was encountered was also fixed.

I wish someday the compiler will tell "hey, you need to put this"

Comment: I tried this and even this didn't work for me!